# Adb not working after adb shell stop

Tags: android, shell, adb

So I think I did something wrong. At first everything was working alright. I was able to see my device when using `adb devices` and process shell commands. The problem began when I was trying out a faster way to flash my systemimage. I came across a website that had just what I needed. At first I was building my systemimage everytime, but overtime it became too long for minor corrections. So I tried syncing via adb. The commands I was using were `adb remount` `adb shell stop` `adb sync` and `adb shell start` in that order. One time I forgot to use the adb shell start and from that point on I cannot see my device under adb devices.

My question is could not running `adb shell start` after stopping it, really break the system that much. Or am I looking for the problem in the wrong place.

Also worth mentioning I am still able to flash systemimages via bootloader so I don't think the problem is usb related.

Comment: i am not sure but just open your task manager and stop your adb process then after restart your adb and it's work for me

Comment: I have already tried that and no change. Both the tabled and computer have been reseted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I fixed it. I don't if shell commands were the problem, but flashing everything (not only systemimage) seemed to fix the problem.